# How can I put the Data from a List into a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, winforms, datagridview

I'm desperately trying to get the contents of a List<> full of Data from a MYSQL Database into a Datagridview.
The part of my Dataprovider Class that fills the List of "Saal"

```
public static List<Saal> ImportSaele()
{
    List<Saal> saallist = new List<Saal>();
    string sql = "Select SID, Name from saele";

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read() == true)
        {
            Saal sa = new Saal();
            sa.id = Convert.ToUInt32(reader["SID"]);
            sa.name = (reader["Name"]).ToString();

            saallist.Add(sa);
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    return saallist;
}
```

And here the part where I tried to import it into the Datagridview(dgv_saele):

```
//Import Of Data
Saalliste = Dataprovider.ImportSaele();
dgv_saele.DataSource = Saalliste;
```

The "Saalliste" gets filled with the required data without any problems, but it won't show it in the Datagridview.

I tried putting a refresh behind it and some other stuff I found but nothing seemed to work. I always get an [empty Gray field...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYRKD.png)
Also sorry in advance for the half German coding, we're forced to do it like that...

Comment: Try using `BindingList` instead of `List`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this did not work, I tried just replacing every List with BindingList and it didn't work and then I tried this with a dgv_saele.Refresh(); behind it and it didn't work either.

Comment: Does the class `Saal` expose any public properties?  It could just be your stylistic requirements, but `sa.id` implies to me that `id` is field and not a property.

Comment: @TnTinMn Saal has these properties:
public class Saal
    {
        public UInt32 id;
        public string name;
        public int seats;


    }

Comment: If `public class Saal { public UInt32 id; public string name; public int seats; } ` is the actual definition, then those are fields not properties. For id to be a property, it would be defined `public Uint32 id {get; set;}`.  Please confirm the definition.  Databinding only works with properties.

Comment: @TnTinMn Now it works, yes I accidentally had this as my code and this was why it wouldn't work. Thank you so much :)
Also how can I mark a comment as the answer? (sorry I'm pretty new here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @TnTinMn Saal has these properties: public class Saal { public UInt32 id; public string name; public int seats; } – Julian Kruste

WinForm data binding is based on binding to properties.

Change the definition of `Saal` to:

```
public class Saal
{
    public UInt32 Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Seats {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your List is empty, the DataGridView would create the Columns automatically. But it is possible to deactivate or manipulate the column creation at design or runtime.

The Designer-Code can help us out.

I assume that your List is not empty.

You can try this AutoGenerateColumns-Property by DataGridView, but this is true by default.

```
dgv_saele.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I tried putting this directly after InitializeComponent(); and that didn't work. Then I tried putting it directly above the setting of the data source and it still wouldn't work.
Also regarding the List being empt: it starts out as empty but then gets filled with 2 sets of data (each has id, name,...) through the Data Provider.ImportSaele();